# How to add custom model data in cart programmatically in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, model, custom

i created custom model(e.g. 'Sample' model) and create one table(fields are like name,price,description) and their fields value store in form input type so i want to add their data in cart so how can i achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean that you're trying to load a model:

```
Mage::getModel('module/sample')->load(1234)
```

And then write some/all of its data to the *checkout session* model:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setSampleDescription($sampleModel->getDescription())
```

This will effectively write a value to `$_SESSION['checkout']['sample_description']` and remain for the duration of this particular session's lifetime.

Now you can access this value:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout')->getSampleDescription();
```

See this answer for a deeper explanation about working with sessions in Magento: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9805663/1442685